# Google AppEngine Bulkloader High Replication Data Delay

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

In the [AppEngine Bulkloader Documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html), they state "If you attempt to copy from a High Replication datastore, you'll see a high_replication_warning error in the Admin Console, and the downloaded data might not include recently saved entities." Any idea how recent they mean by "recently saved entities"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of eventual consistency. Recently saved entities includes anything that wouldn't show up in the query the bulkloader uses. There isn't a firm time horizon on this, but it's usually fairly short (a few seconds).